# Name for two function the sum of which is a PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, definition

A continuous random variable $X$ is defined in a domain $A$ which is the union of two non-overlaping subdomains $B$ and $C$. When analysing the distribution of $X$, one could calculate the PDF of $X$ considering the whole domain $A$, or two PDFs, one for each subdomain separately.

It proved more useful to calculate two functions, one for each subdomain, normalized in such a way that the integral of each function equals the relative size of the subdomain to the whole domain. The sum of these two functions is a PDF, but not each one individually. Is there a name for such a function?

Comment: Would "partial probability distribution function" work?

Comment: It's a mixture distribution.

Comment: I understand that the sum of those two functions is a mixture distribution. Is there a name to refer to each of the functions?

Comment: Mixand or mixture component

Comment: Thank you, dnqxt! I would like to accept it as the answer to register it for future users. If you don't mind, could you please copy it into the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functions may be called mixands or mixture components.